# Evaluating softmax (classification) accuracy in Tensorflow with round or argmax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, softmax

## Problem

I tried to make a softmax classifier with Tensorflow and predict with `tf.argmax()`. I found out that one of `y_` is always higher than 0.5, and I've used `tf.round()` instead of `tf.argmax()`.

However, the gap of accuracy between those two methods is about 20% - the accuracy with `tf.round()` is higher than `tf.argmax()`.

I expected the accuracy of those two methods should be exactly the same or that `tf.round()` should be lower than `tf.argmax()`, but it's not. Does anyone know why this is the case?

## Y and y_

```
Y=[[1,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[0,0,1], ......]  : One-hot (target)

y_=[[0.92, 0.4, 0.4],
[0.2,0.6,0.2],
[0.2,0.4,0.2], ......] : output of softmax
```

## Correct prediction

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(y), tf.round(y_))
```

## Accuracy

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old but someone might stumble accross it like I did...

In short:

- `tf.argmax` reduces one dimension specified by the *axis* argument, it returns the index to the largest value along that *axis*
- `tf.round` rounds each each value, returning the same shape as the input
- the "accuracy" using `tf.round` will increase with length of the dimension specified by *axis*

e.g.

```
y = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
]

y_ = [
    [0.92, 0.4, 0.4],
    [0.2,0.6,0.2],
    [0.2,0.4,0.2]
]

print('argmax shape:', tf.argmax(y_, 1).shape)
print('round shape:', tf.round(y_).shape)

with tf.Session():
    print('argmax value', tf.argmax(y_, 1).eval())
    print('round value', tf.round(y_).eval())

    correct_prediction_argmax = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    correct_prediction_round = tf.equal(tf.round(tf.cast(y, tf.float32)), tf.round(y_))
    print('argmax accuracy:', tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction_argmax, tf.float32)).eval())
    print('round accuracy:', tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction_round, tf.float32)).eval())
```

Output:

```
argmax shape: (3,)
round shape: (3, 3)
argmax value [0 1 1]
round value [[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
argmax accuracy: 0.6666667
round accuracy: 0.8888889
```

You can see that using `tf.round` usually gets *points* for the two extra zeros on each row.